# Editing html using Simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am working through using simple_html_dom.php to scrape and edit/manipulate the following:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$_GET["name"];

$html_code="https://hwb.wales.gov.uk/Home/Pages/Home.aspx";
$html_code= $html_code.$name."/?lang=en";

echo $html_code;


$html = file_get_html($html_code);

echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<meta charset='UTF-8'>";
echo  "<title>PHP Test</title>";
echo " </head>";
echo " <body>";


foreach($html->find('#LatestNewsArts') as $e)
   // Code here to append hwb.wale.gov.uk to <img src="/   >
  echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

echo " </body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

I can extract the `<div>` that I'm looking for - and echo it -- that works fine.

Where I hit a wall (my .php-fu is letting me down) is how to I intercept and edit the html inside the e$ that I have scraped?

What I am looking to do, is replace the  `<img src="/....">`    tag with `<img src="hwb.wales.gov.uk/....">`

Comment: `prepend hwb.wales.gov.uk to each of the 3 that are returned` => Could you give me please what code exactly you want to prepend to these 3 divs ?

Comment: Or you mean replace the simple `<img ... />` tag with `<a href="hwb.wale.gov.uk"><img ... /></a>` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion:  Change <img src="/SiteCollec....... to <img src="hwb.wales.gov.uk/SiteCollec......  

Going from a relative url to a fully described static url

Cheers

Comment: Ow, my bad, that should be easy... i'll post a solution shortly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a new value to an attribute can easily be done like this: `$elmt->attribute = NewValue`

Here's a working code answering your question:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$html_code="https://hwb.wales.gov.uk/Home/Pages/Home.aspx";

// => I dont know what $name stands fore... It's up to you to change this code to suit your needs
//$html_code= $html_code.$name."/?lang=en";

echo $html_code;

$html = file_get_html($html_code);

echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<meta charset='UTF-8'>";
echo  "<title>PHP Test</title>";
echo " </head>";
echo " <body>";

// Loop through all divs with id="Article"
foreach($html->find('#LatestNewsArts #Article') as $e){
    $url = "https://hwb.wales.gov.uk" . $e->find("img",0)->src;

    // Set src to the new $url
    $e->find("img",0)->src = $url;

    // Print the outertext
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';
}

echo " </body>";
echo "</html>";


// Clear dom object
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

=> [Working Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kcn-w34) <=

Comment: Excellent stuff - works a treat.  And I understand what's happening - spot on.